# How can I render a React component inside a DOM node retrieved via class name?

Tags: reactjs, class, dom, root, getelementsbyclassname

HTML:

```html
<body>
    <div class="root"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
    return ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementsByClassName("root")
    );
}

export default App;
```

When this code gets compiled I get the following  "Error: Target container is not a DOM element."

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You are fetching multiple elements instead of one. The second argument in `ReactDOM.render` should be an element, not a list of elements.
- In case you want to go using `class` instead of `id`, it might be more prudent to use `document.querySelector(".root")` as your second argument.

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementsByClassName() gives an array in return instead of an element.

You can either do something like this -

```
document.getElementsByClassName("root")[0]
```

or change do getElementById("root");
and change class="root" to id="root".

Answer (score 2):

the method `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object and not a DOM element like react-dom requires ([DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)).

In case you want to quesry a single DOM element with a class name you can use the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method which returns the first element within the document that matches the specified selector

```
document.querySelector(".root")
```